# JavaScript insertBefore function is not working Properly

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the insertBefore function in javascript but it's not working, It's not returning any error but not inserting any element. But When I used append function for same it works. I am confused about it. Please advise what should I do ??

```
let checkout__button = document.querySelectorAll(".shopify-payment-button__button");
checkout__button.forEach(function (response) {
  let cloneBtn = response.cloneNode(true);
  cloneBtn.classList.add("plusbooster__btn","__beforeCheckout_trigger");
  response.parentNode.insertBefore(cloneBtn, response);
  response.classList.add("PB_hidden");
});
```

Comment: Could you please create an example that show the issue in a reproducible way? I have used that code with some `dummy` html markup and is working fine.

Comment: What exactly do you want to insert exactly before what?

Comment: You cannot pass Arrays to `classList.add()`, only Strings. To add several classes, you need to call `classList.add()`for each one of the classes separately, otherwise it won't work in IE 11 and below.

Comment: So you get a list of buttons, clone each one and insert it before the original button, then add a CSS class that suggests you're hiding the original button. You probably won't notice the difference then...

Comment: Why are you putting the arguments to `classList.add()` in arrays?

Comment: @connexo It should convert the arrays to strings. Converting an array with one element will simply return that element.

Comment: @connexo: here is the URL : 
https://upselltest112.myshopify.com/products/anti-wrinkle-reusable-chest-pad-medical-grade-silicone-invisible-anti-aging-pad-remove-and-prevent-chest-wrinkles

and I want to insert "BUY IT NOW" clone button, just before original.

Comment: @Shidersz : Yes, it worked very well when I used it in console, but the problem is when I put that code inside the JS file it doesn't work and if I change the code to `append` it works that means my JS files loads well.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes that was my mistake but I changed it to comma separated string. I can update my question so it would be helpful for other StackOverflow users. Thanks for pointing to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using `parentNode` instead of `parentElement` (not sure though).

Personally, I prefer to use `insertAdjacentElement`, it's a lot more versatile than `insertBefore` (and you don't need to do that ugly `parentNode/Element` call).

```
response.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', cloneBtn);
```